# Using ng-route with Google-Apps-Script or some means of rendering a partial html view

Tags: angularjs, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to get `ng-route` working with a google-apps-script web app. I have managed to get basic angular.js functionality working with google-apps-script, but I can't seem to get `ng-route` to work. I have placed  ng-view tags inside a page and have included a separate JavaScript page that contains the routeProvider function.

The ng-view never gets rendered and as far as I can make out the routeProvider does not get called.

Can anyone offer any advice on using `ng-route` with google-apps-script or suggest another way of rendering a partial html page with google-apps-script

Any answers greatly appreciated.

Have simplified my code and added below:
Code.gs

```js
    function doGet(e) {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

    // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
    return template.evaluate()
        .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    }

    function getScriptUrl() {
     var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
        return url;
    }
```

index.html

```html
    <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import common stylesheet. -->
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
  <html>
      <body ng-app="myApp">
      <h1>NG View</h1>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
 
      <p>angular check {{'is' + 'working!'}}</p>
 
         <? var url = getScriptUrl();?>
         <p id="urlid"><?=url?></p>
         </body>
    </html>
    <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

Javascript.html

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.js">  </script>
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script>
  angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

  .config(function($routeProvider){
     console.log('routeProvider config');
   var url = document.getElementById("urlid").innerHTML;
   console.log('routeProvider config->' +url);
   $routeProvider.when("/",
   {
     templateUrl:  url+"?page=_app.html",
     controller: "AppCtrl",
     controllerAs: "app"
   }
   );
    })
    .controller('AppCtrl', function() {
      var self = this;
      self.message = "The app routing is working!";
    });
    </script>
```

_app.html

```html
    <div>
      <h1>{{ app.message }}</h1>
    </div>
```

When this runs angular check `{{'is' + 'working!'}}` works fine, but the ng-view does not get rendered the java console shows:

> Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.

Answer (score 0):

The first obstacle is "sce"

$sce is a service that provides Strict Contextual Escaping services to AngularJS.
Refer link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl

For the purpose of investigation, I disabled sce (this is not recommended, though)

$sceProvider.enabled(false);

Now the error is shifted to XMLHttpRequest cannot load... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

XHR requests to the Google Apps Script server are forbidden
Refer link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions

Google Apps is delivering the files from a different origin than the scripts.google.com and angular js client code is not able to fetch the partial htmls from the same origin.

I guess approach of ng-view is not feasible given the restrictions placed by google apps.

Here is the final modified code

```
<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider,$sceProvider){
$sceProvider.enabled(false);
console.log('routeProvider config');
var url = document.getElementById("urlid").innerHTML;
console.log('routeProvider config->' +url);
$routeProvider.when("/",
{
 templateUrl:  url+"?page=_app.html",
 controller: "AppCtrl",
 controllerAs: "app"
}
);
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.message = "The app routing is working!";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, I tried your code and got the same result, that looks conclusive to me that I can't use ng-view to render partial page and assign controllers, any one got other idea's how to handle partial pages in google app script

Answer (score 0):

There has been some time since the question, but I'll post a reply either way.

If your partial html page is not too complicated and big, you can use template instead of templateUrl in the routeProvider, plus create a variable with the html you want to show. Something like this below:

```
var partial_page = "<span>partial page</span>"
 $routeProvider.when("/",
   {
     template:  partial_page,
     controller: "AppCtrl",
     controllerAs: "app"
   }
```

It worked for me, but I wouldn't advise doing so for a complicated partial page as it may become difficult to read the code